# How to close connection at the end of method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

Hi I wanted to ask about how to close the connection at the end of the method, while second method get called.

```
@Transactional(value = "transactionManagerDC")
public void Execute()
{
     // 1. select from DB - took 2 min
     ExecuteAPI()

}; 

public void ExecuteAPI()
{
  // API CALL

};
```

But the longer API call keep the transaction open and put into ideal and terminated. How to commit and close the transaction before the API call method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a transaction is declared using a @Transactional annotation it will end (commit or rollback) when the program control returns from the annotated method, either normally or when an exception occurs.

To have more control over the transactional execution, I would inject a `PlatformTransactionManager` and use a `TransactionTemplate` programatically instead of this declarative approach.

This is a fairly good tutorial on programmatic control over the transactions:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-programmatic-transaction-management

---

In your example, you want to end the transaction before the API call, basically after selecting your data. I'm failing to see why do need a transaction in the first place.

Comment: Hi @David I simplified the code actually there are is business logic before executeAPI() method that do DB operations and required transactions, but once it calls to executeAPI() is should commit and close the session.

Answer (score 0):

```
finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```